# How to do consecutive difference in raster stack data?

Tags: r, r-raster

Assume that I have large RasterBrick, and I would like to do consecutive difference, which means layer2-layer1, layer3-layer2, layer4-layer3, ……..

I was thinking to use Raster package for this, but i am not able to do it.  Could any one suggest me a working (guessing) code please ? I am not providing reproducible data thinking that the issue is clear. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8):

The following seems to work:

```
library(raster)
r1 = raster()
r2 = raster()
r3 = raster()
dim(r2)
r1[] = runif(180*360)
r2[] = runif(180*360)
r3[] = runif(180*360)
r = stack(r1,r2,r3)
dim(r)
rd = calc(r, fun = diff)
dim(rd)
```